# Vertical Scrollbar in CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, scroll, clistctrl

I'm using a CListCtrl in Icon view, but it scrolls horizontally:

```
1 3 5 7 -->
2 4 6 8 -->
```

I'd rather it scroll horizontally:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
| |
V V
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the Alignment style in designer from Left to Top.

Comment: This does not suffice; see my fuller answer.

Comment: this worked perfectly for me in a listcontrol filled with image thumbnails

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have resolved the issue by using a 'Report' view. Through the VS Designer this means changing the 'View' style to Report, resulting the control given the LVS_REPORT attribute in the .RC file.  Note that this is equivalent to calling `CListCtrl::SetView(LV_VIEW_DETAILS)` in code. This isn't sufficient however. It is also necessary to create a column if you don't already have one with a couple lines of code:

```
m_lstScenarios.InsertColumn(0, L"NO HEADER");
m_lstScenarios.SetColumnWidth(k_nListColScenario, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE);
```

If you don't want the column header, set the LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER in the Designer through the 'No Column Header' style.

Answer (score 0):

On the Visual Studio dialog editor, make sure you have a "List Control," not a "List Box."

On the Visual Studio dialog editor's property list, set "No Column Header" to True and "View" to Report.  (Setting "Alignment" to Left has no effect in Report mode.)

In `OnInitDialog()`, do the following (after calling your superclass's `OnInitDialog()`):

```
  CListCtrl* plistError = (CListCtrl*) GetDlgItem( IDC_ERROR );
  plistError->InsertColumn( 0, "" );
  plistError->SetColumnWidth( 0, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER );
```

In fact, that seems to give a maximum autosize of the *initial* width the control is created with.  Strings are displayed truncated with an ellipsis at that point.  Widening the window does not help.

To correct that, add a method `OnSize()` to your `CDialog` subclass that again reminds the list that it's wider.  (This assumes that widening the window is what would let the `CListCtrl` display more text.  If you have some other means, such as a button, try this `SetColumnWidth()` call where you're doing that.)

```
 WinProgress::OnSize() {
    CListCtrl* plist = (CListCtrl*) GetDlgItem( IDC_ERROR );
    plist->SetColumnWidth( 0, LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER );
```

You may then add new rows to the bottom of the list with code such as:

```
  CListCtrl* plist = (CListCtrl*) GetDlgItem( IDC_ERROR );
  int iCount = plist->GetItemCount();

  plist->InsertItem( iCount, "Next Item" );
```

Items too wide for the list will show ellipses at first.  When you resize the window however slightly, then the list items wide to full size and a horizontal scrollbar appears if necessary.  It's not quite 10/10 as far as look and feel are concerned but even experienced GUI programmers probably won't notice.

Answer (score -1):

In list control,to display content with image in single column with vertical scrollbar .add  following code,
In PreCreateWindow function,add following line
cs.style |= (LVS_REPORT|LVS_NOCOLUMNHEADER);
and in OnIntialUpdate function add following line,
    fileList.InsertColumn(0," ",LVCFMT_LEFT|LVCFMT_IMAGE,120,-1);
    ShowScrollBar(SB_VERT,1);
after this,whereever you want to insert data in list you can but take care that you set imagelist and then insert data using insertitem eg:
   fileList,insertitem(0,"India",1);
where 1-> is index  of image in  imagelist.