# CListCtrl Vertical Scrollbar in List View

Tags: c++, mfc, scroll, clistctrl

I have a `CListCtrl` in "List" view mode and I can't get it to scroll vertically instead of horizontally.

I've tried the suggesting here: [Vertical Scrollbar in CListCtrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806669/vertical-scrollbar-in-clistctrl) but that only works when using the icon view mode. It doesn't work in list mode.

So, how can I get my `CListCtrl` in list view mode to scroll vertically?

Comment: You can't. It works the way Microsoft intended for it to work.

Comment: If you can suffer through only using one column you can use Report view.

Comment: I ended up switching to using a CListBox which is a much better solution for what I needed it to do and is easy to select which scrollbars to show.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?
"Change the Alignment style in designer from Left to Top."
[Vertical Scrollbar in CListCtrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806669/vertical-scrollbar-in-clistctrl)